# fprintf not works with scanf in c

Tags: c

this is a part of my code. this is very simple but when i open log.txt there isn't anything on this

```
int main()
{

    FILE *fp = fopen("log.txt", "w+");
    fprintf(fp, "%s\t%s\t%s\n", "Date", "Time Execution Time(ms)", "/path");
    char path[200];
    while (1)
    {

        printf("enter path : ");
        scanf("%s", &path);

        fprintf(fp, "%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d\t%ld\t%s\n", tm.tm_year + 1900,
                tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec,
                elapsed, path);
    }
}
```

but with this change is work

```
int main()
{

    FILE *fp = fopen("log.txt", "w+");
    fprintf(fp, "%s\t%s\t%s\n", "Date", "Time Execution Time(ms)", "/path");
    char path[200];

    printf("enter path : ");
    scanf("%s", &path);

    fprintf(fp,"%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d\t%ld\t%s\n", tm.tm_year + 1900, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec,elapsed,path);
}
```

and this code works too :

```
int main()
{

    FILE *fp = fopen("log.txt", "w+");
    fprintf(fp, "%s\t%s\t%s\n", "Date", "Time Execution Time(ms)", "/path");

    while (1)
    {

        fprintf(fp, "%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d\t%ld\t%s\n", tm.tm_year + 1900,
                tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec,
                elapsed, "kkjk");
    }
}
```

but i don't know why first code not works . please help me

Comment: The last program would be an infinite loop. As is the first program. You should exit the loop at some point.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &path)` should be `scanf("%s", path)`.

Comment: Always close a file if you're done processing it.

Comment: Your example won't compile - where are `tm` and `elapsed` defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running into a buffering problem.

In your second example, where the application quits, there is an implicit `fclose()` that will write all data to disk for you.

Try adding `fflush(fp)` after your writes in the loop, to force a flush of any pending writes.

Or look at [`setvbuf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html) if you want to disable / change the buffering.
Try adding `setlinebuf(fp)` after your `fopen()`, to make the steam line buffered - effectively the system will call `fflush()` on your behalf when a new line (`\n`) is written.

The reason that your last program works is that you're filing the default block buffer very quickly, and carrying on. If you check, the file will not actually be in sync with where you think it is until that next block has been filled and written to disk.
You can try this by running your first example again. This time give *lots* of input - eventually you'll see a whole load of data appears in the file, then *nothing, nothing*, and then lots more.

Comment: thanks a lot . my problem have been solved with fflush